# How to make a grouped bar plot

Tags: r, bar-chart

How do I get this in a grouped barplot? Satisfaction the (1,2,2.5,3) on the x axis and a bar for each (yes,no).
Delaytable

|  | no | yes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1293 | 1706 |
| 2 | 11350 | 12237 |
| 2.5 | 0 | 2 |
| 3 | 25002 | 11982 |

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

```
satisfaction <- c(1,2,2.5,3)
no <- c(1293, 11350,0,25002)
yes <- c(1706, 12237, 2, 11982)

df <- data.frame(satisfaction, no, yes)
df

df_tidy <- df %>% pivot_longer(!satisfaction, names_to = "type", values_to = "count")

ggplot(df_tidy, aes(x = satisfaction, y = count, fill = type)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In base R you could do:

```r
df <- read.table(text="     no  yes
1   1293    1706
2   11350   12237
2.5     0   2
3   25002   11982")

barplot(do.call(rbind, asplit(df, 2)), las=1, beside=TRUE, legend.text = TRUE,
        args.legend = list(x="topleft"), xlab="Satisfaction")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>